# The user interface is stuck when clicking the cancel button or selecting a file on the file dialog box. python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python development. I am trying to create a sample client server project using python. I have created a chat box UI using tkinter. Now I want to popup filedialog box on click of a button. The dialog box is opening but when I click on cancel or select a file then app is stuck. The following is the read file sample I am using.

```
def readFile(self):
    self.Window.overrideredirect(True)
    self.Window.geometry('0x0+0+0')
    self.Window.deiconify()
    self.Window.lift()
    self.Window.focus_force()
    self.Window.sourceFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=self.Window, initialdir= "/",
    title='Please select a directory')
    self.Window.destroy()
    print(self.Window.sourceFile)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish with the code that you have shown, but I have tried running the function (assuming the `self.Window` is a `Tk` or `Toplevel`) and it works without any issue, we will need to see some more of your code to understand what is causing the app to get *stuck*

Comment: Hi, I am trying to develop a client server application. I copied code from this sample. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-multi-threading-python/ now I want to add feature of sending file instead of plaintext. To select a file I am using the above code. Above code is showing dialog box appropriately but on closing or selecting a folder UI is stuck in client application.